# How can I plot two line charts both with standard deviation error in one chart? (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, line

I have plot these two lines in Python. I want also to add the standard deviation to both plots, but currently it works online for one line plot. How can I add the standard deviation to the second line? (see image).

This is my code:

```
lower_bound = np.array(final_list_acc_test) - np.array(final_list_acc_test_std)
upper_bound = np.array(final_list_acc_test) + np.array(final_list_acc_test_std)

#Zum Plotten der finalen Mittelwert Accuracys für jede Neuronenanzahl
neuron = [5,10,15,20,25,30]
N = len(neuron)
neuron_quantity = np.arange(N)
plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))

plt.plot(neuron_quantity, final_list_acc_test, label="Out-Sample Accuracy", 
color="blue")
plt.fill_between(neuron_quantity, lower_bound, upper_bound, color="deepskyblue")


plt.plot(neuron_quantity, final_list_acc_train, label="In-Sample Accuracy", 
color="orange")
plt.fill_between(neuron_quantity, lower_bound, upper_bound, color="green")


plt.xticks(neuron_quantity,neuron)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("Anzahl an Neuronen pro Schicht")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.title('Accuracy für Neuronales Netz mit 1 Hidden Layers & relu als 
Aktivierungsfunktion', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[std_deviation only works for one line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFgXx.png)

Comment: You probably want to calculate a different set of bounds for `final_list_acc_train`, rather than using the ones for `final_list_acc_test`?

Comment: Indeed, you need something like `lower_bound_train = np.array(final_list_acc_train) - np.array(final_list_acc_train_std)` and same for `upper` and then adjust `plt.fill_between(neuron_quantity, lower_bound, upper_bound, color="green")` accordingly.